# What did Soran experience in the Nexus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu, star-trek-generations

In Star Trek: Generations we see Picard’s and Kirk’s idea of a perfect life, even though the former only stayed in the Nexus for a few minutes.

What do you think Soran’s perfect existence in the Nexus was? Was it ever mentioned in the E.U.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StarTrek.com's [official page for Soran](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/soran) describes him as using the nexus "*as an escapist portal for returning his dead family to virtual life with him*"

In the film 'Star Trek : Generations' Guinan [describes](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html) life within the nexus as

> "*like being inside joy. As if joy was something tangible ...and you
>   could wrap yourself in it like a blanket*".

Later, during his first encounter with Soran, Picard attempts to reason with him by highlighting the amorality of his actions;

> "PICARD: *What you're about to do Soran, is no different from when the
>   Borg destroyed your world. They killed millions too,* **including your
>   wife and children**.
>
> SORAN: *Nice try. You know, there was a time when I wouldn't hurt a
>   fly.* **Then the Borg came**. *And they showed me that if there is one
>   constant in this whole universe it's death.*
>
> *Afterwards I began to realise it didn't really matter. We're all going to die sometime. It's just a question of how and when. You will
>   too, Captain. Aren't you beginning to feel time gaining on you?*
>
> *It's like a predator. It's stalking you. Oh, you can try and outrun it with doctors, medicines, new technologies, but in the end time is
>   going to hunt you down and make the kill.*
>
> PICARD: *It's our mortality that defines us, Soran. It's part of the
>   truth of our existence.*
>
> SORAN: *What if I told you I've found a new truth.*
>
> PICARD: *The Nexus?*
>
> SORAN: **Time has no meaning there. The predator has no teeth**."

Soran is clearly attempting to enter the nexus in order to avoid his *own* mortality and to return to a time (even if virtual) when his family was still alive.

On top of that, the nexus creates an artificial sense of 'joy' that is so attractive that Guinan thinks that anyone would be tempted to stay, regardless of their mental strength.

If Soran's experience is anything like Picard and Kirk's then he can expect to be shown a mish-mash of scenarios that are intended to represent his various longings and regrets made whole.

Answer (score 6):

The movie mentions that Soran has lost his family (as far as I recall during a Borg attack - yup, seems [correct](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tolian_Soran)). I assume he hoped to be reunited with them (actually the linked article specifically says so, but I'm no expert on Star Trek Canon Levels).

Comment: No reference on the page, which generally means it came from the obvious place:  the movie he appeared in, rather than a novelization or something.  If it's not in the movie, it may be an assumption that snuck in when the page was being written...

Comment: Actually I meant that I have no idea if Memory Alpha would be a proper source for a "proper" fan (I know that proper sources are important to fans, alas I'm just a guy who happens to remember that movie).

Comment: In that case:  Memory Alpha does its best to stick to canon, leaving non-canon (novels/games/etc) to Memory Beta, or putting it under the "Apocrypha" section if it's especially relevant.  It's a good resource for Star Trek, that I've used for _tons_ of answers on here.

Comment: MA is pretty much the de facto resource for Star Trek canon.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz True, but like most wikis they have plenty of unreferenced assertions that have just "crept in" and are now accepted as being nearly canonical despite simply being one person's opinion.